# I have deleted page from word press site but it still appears on same url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have deleted page from word press site but it still appears on same url i also deleted the same page from trash and deleted permanently but now when i open the same page url it appers the same page on same url which i delete

Any Solution?

Comment: Are you using any chaching plugin like wp-supercache or anything??

Answer (score 1):

Seems the page is cached. try to add a query string to the page (e.g. *your_page/?no-cache), if the page won't appear with this link - clear all available caches (e.g cache plugin or host / server cache)

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly is caching. Please clear the cache then check your deleted page will no longer accessible.

If still you are facing issue then

Try this

1. Create new page named "Your choice"
2. Go to "woocommerce" > "Settings" > "Product" > "Display tab"
3. Select shop page named "Shop" then click save changes.
4. Back to "Pages" then delete "Shop" page (Remove the page from trash,
   delete permanently)

If still its won't work redirect it to home page using below plugin:
[Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: i have cleared the super cache but i still got the same thing can you please tell me what other problem it can be?

Comment: can you please share the URL of deleted page